# Creating "ring shaped" buttons in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a Simon game using HTML, CSS and jQuery. My design is based on [this game on iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/circles-memory-game/id586168287?platform=ipad&preserveScrollPosition=true#platform/ipad).

I'd really like to get the buttons to look like rings!

I've tried a few solutions using a relative parent div and absolute children divs but the problem is that because I'm using Bootstrap Grid System and it's responsive; when I inspect the web page to adjust the divs position or adjust the screen ratio everything moves around and it looks terrible.

Using `box-shadow: inset` on the button to create the ring has been the most promising but I'm already using box-shadow to create a neon glow that it isn't really an option for me. (If there is a way to do both this could be promising.)

```css
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}

#btn1 {
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px blue, 0 0 30px blue, 0 0 40px blue, 0 0 55px blue, 0 0 75px blue;
}

#btn2 {
  background-color: Red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px red, 0 0 30px red, 0 0 40px red, 0 0 55px red, 0 0 75px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">
    <button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">1</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

ANy help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: can you show us the expected output ?

Comment: check out https://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/ it lists all the solutions for non-standard shadows. If you are ok with not supporting IE, you might consider `filter: drop-shadow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what u want?

In the example, i added 2 box shadows for the buttton. using

```
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 255, 20, 0.69), inset 0 0 0px 7px rgb(0, 255, 20);
```

first one for outer glow, and second for creating the ring.

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}

.btn-circle:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.ring1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 255, 20, 0.69), inset 0 0 0px 7px rgb(0, 255, 20);
}

.glowbtn {
  background-color: #00ff14;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 255, 20, 0.69);
}

.border-ring {
  background: transparent;
  border: 8px solid #00ff14;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 255, 20, 0.69);
}

.inner-glow {
  background: transparent;
  border: 8px solid #00ff14;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 255, 20, 0.69), inset 0 0 20px 7px rgba(0, 255, 20, 0.69);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">


  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl ring1">3</button>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl glowbtn">3</button>
  </div>
  <br/>


  <h3>Can be created using only border and box shadow</h3>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl border-ring">3</button>
  </div>


  <h3>ring button with inner glow</h3>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl inner-glow">3</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Absolutley spot on! The ring with the inner glow is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks for this, I've been scratching my head for awhile with this problem. Seems so obvious now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inset` on some of your shadows and not others. This will make some of the shadows cast inwards and others outwards. Also, replace your 
`background-color` rule with `border`.

```css
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
}

#btn1 {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue, /*0 0 10px #fff,*/ 0 0 20px blue inset, 0 0 30px blue inset, 0 0 40px blue, 0 0 55px blue, 0 0 75px blue;
}

#btn2 {
  border: 5px solid Red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px red, /*0 0 10px #fff,*/ 0 0 20px red inset, 0 0 30px red inset, 0 0 40px red, 0 0 55px red, 0 0 75px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px;">
  <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3">
    <button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">1</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check the snippet and here you can find it in

fiddle with SCSS https://jsfiddle.net/ckm1qwgq/

and if you want to make the **shadow** more you can change the value of the *box shadow*

example

```
box-shadow: 0 0 12px 5px #03cafc;
```

to

```
box-shadow: 0 0 40px 9px #03cafc;
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.item:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.item:first-child {
  background-color: #03cafc;
}
.item:first-child:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 5px #03cafc;
  background: #03cafc;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ff8f4c;
}
.item:nth-child(2):before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 5px #ff8f4c;
  background: #ff8f4c;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #51eca5;
}
.item:nth-child(3):before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 5px #51eca5;
  background: #51eca5;
}
.item:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: pink;
}
.item:nth-child(4):before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 5px pink;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It wasn't quite what I was looking for but thanks for your time. @GautamNaik provided what I was looking for. I marked it as the answer if you are interested in seeing.